# Cannot connect to vpnc with network-manager 1.2.6

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, vpnc

I tried to connect to a vpn (vpnc type) using two machines with Ubuntu-GNOME 16.04 and 16.10 both with network-manager 1.2.6. The connection is established but then I have no internet connection at all. I tried ticking the option: "Use this connection only for resources on its network" for both IPv4 and IPv6, which gives me internet connection, but then the problem is that I can't access the resources within the vpn network.

On the other hand I have another machine with Ubuntu 15.04 with network-manager 0.9.10.0 which is able to stablish a successful connection. The problem here is that I was planning to update this system in the near future, so I would like to know how to make this work in newer versions.

Many thanks.

## Update (Solved)

@RayB It worked. Many thanks.

Though the correct commands should be:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager=1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.4
sudo service network-manager restart
```

I hope they solve the bug for the next upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known bug in network-manager 1.2.6

Downgrading network-manager is a known solution.

See my answer here for more info. https://askubuntu.com/a/897630/140858